# Lebesgue measure of sets with cardinality greater than $ℵ_1$

Tags: set-theory, lebesgue-measure, cardinals

I am not a mathematician and I am asking this question out of my curiosity.

Lebesgue measure of a set $S$ such that $Cardinality(S)=ℵ_0$ is $0$.

And lebesgue measure of a set $P$ such that $Cardinality(P)=ℵ_1$ is a positive number including infinity (sometimes it can be $0$ too but mostly it is a positive number or infinity.)..

My question is:

What is the Lebesgue measure of a set with cardinality $ℵ_n$ where $n>1$?

Comment: A set of cardinality $\aleph_1$ may have Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: Wait how? Can you please explain further?

Comment: Why can't I edit my question to correct it?

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar Are you on mobile? Presumably someone has submitted an edit and that blocks anyone on mobile from further editing until it has been either rejected or accepted.

Comment: @Arthur, thanks for pointing it out. I forgot about the suggested edit.

Comment: Everyone in the comment. I wanna tell you that I corrected my question and the thing you are talking about is not the focus of this question so I will request to not debate about it further and please help me get the answer for the question "What is the lebesgue measure of a set with cardinality greater that $ℵ_1$?".

Comment: For any $\aleph_0\leq \kappa\leq\mathfrak c$ there are sets of cardinality $\kappa$ and measure zero. For $\kappa=\mathfrak c$ there are sets with any measure in $[0,\infty]$. This is all $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can say.

Comment: The Lebesgue measure hasn't got a lot related to cardinality. The duplicate shows, and as @Alessandro suggests, any set with positive measure has size continuum. But that's all we can say about it.